# @HTML.CheckBoxfor não passa valor ao model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

estou com o seguinte problema: tenho um `checkbox` na página mas mesmo marcando ele, no `controller` o `Model` continua com o campo `lavagem = false`.

**Model**

```
public bool lavagem { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.lavagem, htmlAttributes: new  { id="chkLavagem" })
```

Comment: Poderia mostrar o método do controller, principalmente os parâmetros de entrada? Além disso seria interessante mostrar como está dando o submit a partir da view. Apenas com o código que você colocou, é muito difícil imaginar o que pode estar acontecendo.

Comment: se você trocar de `bool` para `String` ele retorna valores diferentes?

Comment: Pode colocar na sua pergunta o código da *Action* chamada no *Controller*?